# Automated mock that returns for each attribute the attribute name as string

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there an existing fixture, or a simple one that can be created, that would return magically for any attribute of this mock object, as a value a string made by the name of the attribute?

```py
foo = AutoAttributeMock()
assert foo.bar == "bar" # True
assert foo.other == "other" # True
assert foo.third != "bar" # False
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just implement `def __getattr__(self, name): return name`, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, attribute access is done through [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), so it would be possible to simply do the following:

```py
class AutoAttributeMock:
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> str:
        return name
```

Though I struggle to see a reasonable use case for this.

Comment: The use case is for a class that has an object for some config for instance, that is pure data.
I want to mock this object and not create a real one. We only access attributes of this object, it would be very convenient then no to set all attributes accessed, but have them existing automatically.

Comment: @Floh Ok, well, if you are not interested in the actual data behind the attribute, a regular `Mock` should be fine too. It always returns another Mock upon attribute access. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

Comment: Sure and thanks. As values are used to template other strings I was finding convenient to have a deterministic behavior :)

Comment: @Floh Not in principle, though you may want to take a look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.7/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L629) first, if you want to override `__getattr__` and want the behavior of the `Mock` to remain otherwise unaffected. The simplest though not very efficient way would be to call the superclass' method inside and discard the new `Mock` in favor of the attribute name. But I haven't looked into the internal logic deeply enough.